# Python 3 - How to remove line/paragraph breaks

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-docx

```
from docx import Document

alphaDic = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g','h','i','j','k','l','m','n','o','p','q','r','s','t','u','v','w','x','y','z','!','?','.','~',',','(',')','$','-',':',';',"'",'/']

while docIndex < len(doc.paragraphs):
    firstSen = doc.paragraphs[docIndex].text
    rep_dic = {ord(k):None for k in alphaDic + [x.upper() for x in alphaDic]}
    translation = (firstSen.translate(rep_dic))
    removeSpaces = " ".join(translation.split())
    removeLineBreaks = removeSpaces.replace('\n','')
    doc.paragraphs[docIndex].text = removeLineBreaks

    docIndex +=1
```

I am attempting to remove line breaks from the document, but it doesn't work.
I am still getting

```
Hello


There
```

Rather than

```
Hello
There
```

Comment: try replace('\r\n','') ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is get rid of an empty paragraph. The following function could help, it deletes a certain paragraph that you don't want:

> ```
> def delete_paragraph(paragraph):
>     p = paragraph._element
>     p.getparent().remove(p)
>     p._p = p._element = None
> ```
>
> Code by: Scanny*

In your code, you could check if translation is equal to `''` or not, and if it is then call the `delete_paragraph` function, so your code would be like:

```
while docIndex < len(doc.paragraphs):
    firstSen = doc.paragraphs[docIndex].text
    rep_dic = {ord(k):None for k in alphaDic + [x.upper() for x in alphaDic]}
    translation = (firstSen.translate(rep_dic))
    if translation != '':
        doc.paragraphs[docIndex].text = translation 
    else:
        delete_paragraph(doc.paragraphs[docIndex])
        docIndex -=1 # go one step back in the loop because of the deleted index

    docIndex +=1
```

*Reference- [feature: Paragraph.delete()](https://github.com/python-openxml/python-docx/issues/33)

Answer (score 1):

The package comes with an [example program](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx/blob/master/example-extracttext.py) that extracts the text.

That said, I think your problem springs from the fact that you are trying to operate on paragraphs. But the separation between paragraphs is where the newlines are happening. So even if you replace a program with the empty string (`''`), there will still be a newline added to the end of it.

You should either take the approach of the example program, and do your own formatting, or you should make sure that you delete any spurious "empty" paragraphs that might be between the "full" ones you have ("Hello", "", "There") -> ("Hello", "There").

Answer (score 0):

Since readlines could read any type of text files, you can open the file rewrite the lines you want and ignore the lines you dont want to use.

```
"""example"""

file = open("file name", "w")
for line in file.readlines():
    if (line != ''):
        file.write(line)
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: Thanks for the advise sear. i will try my best.